# Boilng vodka for A/C cleaning

Tags: boiling-point

I hope this doesn't sound too strange.
I have plenty of cheap vodka and want to clean the A/C on my car.

So I thought about boiling 1/2 litre of vodka in my car while I ran the A/C with recirculation on.
The alcohol should get liquid within the air conditioner and desinfect and clean the vaporizer.

I am just not sure if I create an explosive mixture inside the car this way.

David

Comment: Visit a private mechanic, not a chain operation. What do you expect your porous high surface area upholstery will be doing as you fill your car with booze vapor?

Comment: I have my own garage, I rebuild my whole engine... I don't need a mechanic :)  
I think there should be no problem for the interiour (mostly leather) if there is some steam, that will me immediately sucked by the AC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alcohol vapors can certainly form explosive mixtures with air, so filling the car with ethanol vapors is potentially dangerous. A source of ignition, for example a spark, could under the right circumstances ignite the vapors. If the fan motor of the AC system is a brushed motor it can create small sparks. So I would say there is a fire hazard.
 
But there are other problems with your suggested setup. The ethanol and water vapors would condense on every surface of your car's interior, the windows, the roof, the doors, etc. This would mean you loose a lot of alcohol, so you would need more. Ethanol might attack and start to dissolve some of the interior, glued parts may become loose. And of course the car would smell very strongly like vodka for a long time.
So I would suggest disassembling the dash cluster and whatever else you need to get to the AC system, and using the vodka in liquid form to clean it properly.

Comment: I would advise against using vodka at all. Alcohol 100% (which you'll get from the vapor, depending how you do it) [isn't a good anti-septic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disinfectant#Alcohols). Neither is Alcohol 40% (vodka). Alcohol 70% v/v is much more effective. Want to make good use of that cheap vodka? Drink it.